# Nest loops with read lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am building a dataset based off of a file containing names and descriptions and i recently obtained a file that has the same list of names with item numbers included. I want to be able to either add the item descriptions to the file or just look up the item number and name and see if there any matches in the same line. 
This is just a snippet of the code that has to deal with the newly added second file

File 1 is formatted as such:

> Name
>   Description

File 2 is formatted:
Name Item#

My goal is to be able to pull the names from file 1 and search file 2 for occurances of specific item numbers and output it as a variable to be used in the next part of the code to be output as a csv file along with some other information gained from the item description.

This is my code so far:

```
    for line in file1 :

        if ">" in line:
            name=line[1:7]
            open(file2,"r")
            item1="51257"

            for line in file2:
                i51257=0

                if name and item1 in line:
                    print("1")
                    i51257+=1
                elif name and ps1 not in line:
                    i51257+=0 

            file2.close()

        if ">" not in line:

            counted = Counter(line)

            divisor= str(1000/counted)
            csvout.append(name + "," + divisor + "," + counted + "," + str(i51257))

    csvfinal='\n'.join(csvout)

    file1.close()

    open(csv1, "w")

    csv1.write(csvfinal)

    csv1.close()
```

My expected output should be:

```
Name, Divisor Value, Length of Line, Number of Times Item1 appears
Name, Divisor Value, Length of Line, Number of Times Item1 appears
```

But i am getting a divide by zero error in the divisor line which was not occuring before adding the second file to read from.

Comment: A few things you might want to clean up here. You're using `line` in both your inner and your outer loops here. So by the time you get to that `if ">" not in line` block of code, `line` means something entirely different than it did in the initial `if ">" in line:` line of code. Also, `open(file2,"r")` isn't being stored in a variable. I highly recommend reading Python docs on opening a file with `with`. Example: `with open(file2, 'r') as f:` and then `f.readlines()`

Comment: maybe you should use `else:` instead of `if ">" not in line:`

Comment: I fixed what Taylor V suggested and I am now running through the code fine but it is giving me an output of zero for every name despite by checking manually I can confirm there are instances of some of the names and item 51257 existing on the same line. I replaced ```if name and item1 in line``` with  ``` if name and item1 in f"  ```after ```f.readlines()```.